# What do [] brackets in a for loop in python mean?

Tags: python

I'm parsing JSON objects and found this sample line of code which I kind of understand but would appreciate a more detailed explanation of:

```
for record in [x for x in records.split("\n") if x.strip() != '']:
```

I know it is spliting records to get individual records by the new line character however I was wondering why it looks so complicated? is it a case that we can't have something like this:

```
for record in records.split("\n") if x.strip() != '']:
```

So what do the brackets do []? and why do we have x twice in `x for x in records.split....`

Thanks

Comment: It's a list comprehension, see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341775/what-is-the-advantage-of-a-list-comprehension-vs-for-loop

Comment: EdChum is right (duh); note that it doesn't have to do with loops in particular. This notation is a terse way to create lists. A loop can iterate also over lists.

Comment: Thanks for both of you inputs, on a side note people love down voting question on here. If you're going to vote a question down then I think you should leave a comment saying why. I think it's a valid programming question which I couldn't find anywhere else or know how to search for.

Comment: @Mo. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229059/understanding-this-line-list-of-tuples-x-y-for-x-y-label-in-data-one

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The "brackets" in your example constructs a new list from an old one, this is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

The basic idea with `[f(x) for x in xs if condition]` is:

```
def list_comprehension(xs):
    result = []
    for x in xs:
        if condition:
            result.append(f(x))
    return result
```

The `f(x)` can be any expression, containing `x` or not.

Answer (score 2):

That's a list comprehension, a neat way of creating lists with certain conditions on the fly.

You can make it a short form of this:

```
a = []
for record in records.split("\n"):
    if record.strip() != '':
        a.append(record)

for record in a:
    # do something
```