# How do I match list of sentences with a list of keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

aI want to make a new list that matches from a list of sentences against a list of keywords.

```
list = ['This sentence contains disclosure.', 'This sentence contains none declared.', 'This sentence contains competing interest.', 'This sentence contains authors declare.']
keywords = ['disclosure ', 'none declared', 'interest']
```

The new list should print should come out like this

```
matched_list = ['This sentence contains disclosure.', 'This sentence contains none declared.']
```

I have tried using

```
r = re.compile('.*disclosure')
newlist = list(filter(r.match, list))
```

However I have a very large list of keywords and it will be impossible to type it all out in the `r = re.compile('.*keywords')`. Is there any other way to to match a list of sentences with a list of keywords.

Comment: Try `matched_list = [l for l in lst if any(k in l for k in keywords)]` if regex based matching is not needed.

Comment: @coldspeed thank you so much the matching worked. Is it possible to kind of explain the syntax you used for this code especially with 1 for 1.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/30670310/3001761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to check each string against the keyword list. Use a list comprehension, assuming simple string matching is enough (without the need for regex).

```
matched_list = [
    string for string in lst if any(
        keyword in string for keyword in keywords)]
```

Which is really just a concise way of saying:

```
matched_list = []
for string in lst:
    if any(keyword in string for keyword in keywords):
        matched_list.append(string)
```

`any` will short circuit, returning `True` for the first keyword that matches (or else returns `False` if no match is found).

---

If you want to use regex, you can precompile your pattern and then call `pattern.search` inside a loop, as usual:

```
import re
p = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords)))
matched_list = [string for string in lst if p.search(string)]
```

Comment: Just a additional follow up, is there a way to re modify the code so that instead of getting the list of matched sentence can i get it to tabulate which word got matched? @coldspeed

Comment: @KaungMyat as in return the index of the match? What if there is no match?

Comment: Yes, as in return the index of the match? Just to clarify instead of extracting the entire string of the list, i want to just extract out the matched words and possibly count them. The code you showed me worked perfectly for the part but i am currently working on something else and i tried to modify the code but it seem to not work. @coldspeed

Comment: @KaungMyat Do you want something like `from collections import Counter; counts = Counter(k for s in lst for k in keywords if k in s)`