# Extracting list of tuples using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am trying to extract data's from list of list of tuples but I am having an issue because they have different output from normal for loop and this list comprehension loop:

Here is my sample data and actually came from my database and return it as unicode and I just converted as a list:

```
[[(1970, u'0238'), (1971, u'0243'), (2110, u'0929'), (2108, u'0930'), (1972, u'0932'), (1973, u'0934')]]
[[(1970, u'0238'), (1971, u'0243'), (2110, u'0929'), (2108, u'0930'), (1972, u'0932'), (1973, u'0934')]]
[[(2108, u'0930')], [(3012, u'1')]]
[[(2108, u'0930')], [(3012, u'1')]]
[[(2108, u'0930')], [(3012, u'1')]]
[[(2108, u'0930')], [(3012, u'1')]]
```

And by using my simple for loop which is the correct output:

```
for i in datas:
    print i
[(1970, u'0238'), (1971, u'0243'), (2110, u'0929'), (2108, u'0930'), (1972, u'0932'), (1973, u'0934')]
[(1970, u'0238'), (1971, u'0243'), (2110, u'0929'), (2108, u'0930'), (1972, u'0932'), (1973, u'0934')]
[(2108, u'0930')]
[(3012, u'1')]
[(2108, u'0930')]
[(3012, u'1')]
[(2108, u'0930')]
[(3012, u'1')]
[(2108, u'0930')]
[(3012, u'1')]
```

But if I will use the list comprehension style the out will be now different:

```
print [i for i in datas]
[[(1970, u'0238'), (1971, u'0243'), (2110, u'0929'), (2108, u'0930'), (1972, u'0932'), (1973, u'0934')]]
[[(1970, u'0238'), (1971, u'0243'), (2110, u'0929'), (2108, u'0930'), (1972, u'0932'), (1973, u'0934')]]
[[(2108, u'0930')], [(3012, u'1')]]
[[(2108, u'0930')], [(3012, u'1')]]
[[(2108, u'0930')], [(3012, u'1')]]
[[(2108, u'0930')], [(3012, u'1')]]
```

Any advice or suggestions thanks in advance!

Comment: Your for-loop prints out individual lists. Your list comprehension *creates a big list*. Indeed, it is totally pointless, since `[i for i in datas] == list(datas) == datas`

Comment: Your plain `for` loop is correct, so I'm not sure why you want the listcomp at all. listcomps are a functional programming construct; using them for side-effects (e.g. `print`ing each element) is strongly discouraged. Just use the loop you've got.

Comment: Actually yes, my for loop is already working but what I am trying to do here is to improve it's execution time. I saw this article as my reference that using list comprehension might help to optimize the speed, so that's why I am trying with different solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341775/what-is-the-advantage-of-a-list-comprehension-over-a-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

by for loop, you are printing the items inside the list, but in list comprehension itself creating a outer list.

I think you need,

```
 print sum([i for i in datas],[])
```

Comment: Do *not* use `sum([i for i in datas],[])`, it is an anti-pattern. The docs of `sum` specifically mention it is meant to be used with numeric types. Using it with a sequence type like a `list` will give you O(N^2) behavior, and you can do it with linear time complexity instead

Comment: I consider your suggestion but on this logic the expected result is still not the same.

Comment: Adding to @juanpa.arrivillaga: If you need to do this, the correct approach is `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(datas))`, which is `O(n)` (thanks to `list` appends being amortized `O(1)`).