# how to set item in Qtablewidget using python map function

Tags: python, qt, lambda, pyqt, pyside6

I try to use the map() function to set items of a qtablewidget in this way:

```
x,y = np.meshgrid(range(5),range(10))
map(lambda x,y: self.tab.setItem(x,y,QTableWidgetItem()), x,y)
```

but it is not working, items are not set whereas I have no error. Any idea on what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation of [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) explains, it returns an *iterator* (as opposed to the behavior on Python 2 which called the function in place).

This means that the function will *not* be called until the returned map object is *iterated*.

A possible solution would be to "force" the iteration by converting it to a list:

```
list(map(lambda x, y: self.tab.setItem(x, y, QTableWidgetItem()), x, y))
```

Which is roughly the same as:

```
[self.tab.setItem(x, y, QTableWidgetItem()) for x, y in zip(x, y)]
```

That said, consider that such usage of mapping or comprehensions is usually frown upon, as they do not really provide any benefit:

- there's no performance increase (on the contrary, you're creating a map object and then a list from it);<sup>[1]</sup>
- it makes debugging more difficult;
- it makes the code much less readable (and that's *very* important);

There are very few situations for which using an approach like this is actually required, and a for loop is almost always a better choice.

<sup>[1] list comprehensions offer performance benefits as they actually *build* the list object after all elements have been gathered, while using `list.append()` continuously grows the existing list object (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16341841) answer), but since you're not creating a list that will be *actually* used, those benefits are completely nullified, and a for loop is a clearer, better and faster choice.</sup>